# ActiveResource::Collection is giving NameError

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeresource

[image]

I am trying to run ActiveResource::Collection on console, but its giving name error. Kindly give me a solution to solve this.

```
 NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveResource::Collection
 from (irb):10
 from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
 from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
 from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
 from script/rails:6:in `require'
 from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

**UPDATE**

Others like ActiveResource::Base, ActiveResource::Format, ActiveResource::Connection are working.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have `ActiveResource` added. Add it into your `Gemfile` and run `bundle install`.

```
# Gemfile
gem 'activeresource'

# Command line
bundle install
```

Comment: Did you restart your rails app and rails console?

Comment: ActiveResource::Base WORKING

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by updating activeresource gem version to **activeresource-4.0.0**. Earlier it was **activeresource-3.2.17** .